# Can I create a sub-module inside a module?

Tags: magento2

I have modules with inter-dependencies, such as

- `MyVendor_MyModule1`: `Account`
- `MyVendor_MyModule2`: `Account`
- `MyVendor_MyModule1`: `Auth`
- `MyVendor_MyModule2`: `Auth`
- `MyVendor_MyModule1`: `Config`
- `MyVendor_MyModule2`: `Config`

`Account`namespace contains common code for both `MyModule1` and `MyModule2`.

Currently, I am having a duplicate code in both modules.

I want to make `Account` an independent module to reduce the code duplicacy.

How shall I move forward without messing with namespaces?

Edt:

> To be exact: My current scenario is `\Cj\Amazon` is 1 module.
>   I am planning to break it into two modules, i.e. `Cj\Amazon\Importer`
>   and `\Cj\Amazon\Integration`.
>
> Both uses the same authentication which
>   is `Cj\Amazon\Auth`. But in Magento, we are restricted to use
>   `Vendor\Module` pattern.
>
> Is there any way two have multi modules with
>   same namespaces i.e in `\Cj\Amazon\` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create class Account in the MyVendor_MyModule1 and then extend from it in the MyVendor_MyModule2: Account.

for example

```
<?php
   namespace MyVendor\MyModule1;

   class Account 
   {
      public function someMethod() {}
   }


   namespace MyVendor\MyModule2;

   use MyVendor\MyModule1\Account as FirstAccount;

   class Account extends FirstAccount;
   {
      public function someMethod2() {}
   }
```

Comment: Yes sure I can do this, but both the module should independently also, which will fail the case.

Comment: You can create one more module that named as Base or Core and put all code that you want to use for both Module1 and Module2. If you want to provide Module1 independent of Module2 you can provide Base + Module1 or Base + Module 2

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that, but my current scenario is `\Cj\Amazon` is 1 module.
I am planning to break it into two modules, i.e. `Cj\Amazon\Importer` and `\Cj\Amazon\Integration`. Both uses the same authentication which is `Cj\Amazon\Auth`.
But in Magento, we are restricted to `Vendor\Module` pattern. Is there any way two have multi modules with same namespaces i.e in `\Cj\Amazon` ?